# Resetting a device in device manager

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, device-driver, hardware-acceleration

I am looking for a programmically API on how to restart any device  that allows enable/disable in the device manager,

such as Audio devices and Network adapter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to use [SetupApi](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff550897(v=VS.85).aspx) / [ConfigManager API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff549794(v=VS.85).aspx). But be aware that under x64 you app. must be also x64 to enable/disable device (so you cannot do it  in Delphi directly right now - first I thought that it's a problem with file/registry redirection for x86-app under x64, but it didn't help). Device enumeration works fine. There was something about it in one article on MSDN but I cannot find it right now. I've made FP/Lazarus x64 application for enable/disable devices under x64 OS.

You can download [WDK](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/wdk/wdkpkg.mspx) and look for source code of [DevCon](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311272) (C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\src\setup\devcon). In cmds.cpp there is function ControlCallback which enables/disables device using SetupApi). But first you need to enumerate device classes (by GUID or ClassName), and then enumerate device instances or open device by DeviceInstanceId string. It's in C but it should be easy to learn how to use that API.

Not sure what you are doing, but maybe it would be easier to use that devcon.exe (don't know if license permits it) and enable/disable devices by it?

Comment: Header translations of the mentioned SetupApi and ConfigManager are available in the Jedi Apilib

Comment: Thanks Remko, forgot write about it. About that x86 vs. x64 if you will try to do this you probably end up with error E0000235 (like http://www.techtalkz.com/microsoft-device-drivers/292837-problem-porting-32-bit-application-x64.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with it but I think you can use the [DeviceIoControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363216%28VS.85%29.aspx) API.